# Display posts from json

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have to display posts  from json , but when i try to use for loop  nothing happen ..  Here is My code , what i've do wrong . ty

JS

```
   var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
$.ajax({
 url: root,
 method: 'GET',
 success: function(response) {
 console.log(response);

 jQuery.get('/posts', function(posts) {
    for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
    document.write(posts[i]);
    }
   });
 }
});
```

Any Ideea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
$.ajax({
 url: root+"/posts",
 method: 'GET',
 contentType: 'application/json',
 success: function(posts) {
    console.log("Data=>",posts);
     $.each(posts,function(index,post){
      document.write("<p>"+post.title+"</p>");
    });
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You should give proper URL `root+'/posts'` in order to fetch data from API.

Comment: It's working like this . i understand what i've do wrong , but it's display Object , somethings is wrong again . I need to display posts .

Comment: Yes. you should parse the response as json then access each data using key.

Comment: I already mark you correct answer . in meantime i make it as well . ty :D

Comment: Yes but some mistakes in your ajax call `$.ajax({method="GET"` and `jQuery.get` are same ,only one needed to fetch data from api.

Answer (score 2):

There is wrong in calling API in ajax method.

```
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
    $.ajax({
     url: root+"/posts",
     method: 'GET',
     contentType: 'application/json',
     success : function(data) {
        //The 'data' u recieve here is the response from the api, Use this data to loop through and display it in the web page
      },
     error: function(err) {
      console.log("err");
       }  
     }
    });
```

Try the above snippet, I hope it works

Comment: Basically, don't use jquery.get with in AJAX, because we use AJAX to communicate with our services, we should actually communicate to specific end-point to be mentioned in `url` only. That AJAX request itself hits the end point and gets us the response, There usage of Jquery.get doesn't make sense

Answer (score 1):

You can make it more simple by using `jQuery.get`

```
$.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',function(data){
    $.each(data,function(key,post){
        $('body').append('<p>'+post.title+'</p>');
    });
});
```

check the documentation ( https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ )